# Creating a custom cocoa pod with a storyboard in it

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, cocoapods

I am creating a pod, and in the resource bundle I have a storyboard (localised).

When I try to instantiate a storyboard, an error occurred: `Could not find a storyboard named 'MyStoryboard' in bundle NSBundle`. The code look like this:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[NSBundle mainBundle] URLForResource:@"MyBundle" withExtension:@"bundle"];
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];
UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:@"MyStoryboard" bundle:bundle];
```

MyBundle structure looks like this:

```
- MyBundle.bundle
  - Base.lproj
    - MyStoryboard.storyboard
  - es.lproj
    - MyStoryboard.strings
```

Can storyboard can be included in a bundle in the first place?

I have not seen examples of Pod that includes storyboards. If you know of any pods that share their storyboard, let me know too.

Comment: There's an [issue](https://github.com/CocoaPods/CocoaPods/issues/2597) in the Cocoapods Repo about this. It's basically not possible to do this at the moment.

Comment: I faced the same issue after a long search and extensive SO browsing found a solution which worked for me, added that as an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56643351/3876832) hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 12):

There are two things to keep in mind.

1. You add your pod resources via a predefined bundle like

   ```
   s.resources = ["Resources/Pod.bundle"]
   ```

in this case the content of your bundle will be copied to your xcode project without any "further processing". This means that storyboards or xib files will not be compiled and won't be available in your project.

2. You can explicitly mention your storyboard/nib files like

   ```
   s.resources = ["Resources/**/*.storyboard"]
   ```

In this case the storyboard will be compiled and will be available in your project. The downside of this (at the moment of this writing) is that you can not use localized storyboards, because all storyboards will be processed and copied at the root location of your bundle. So storyboards with the same name in different `.lproj` folders will be overwritten.

Answer (score 4):

You want the [`resources`](http://guides.cocoapods.org/syntax/podspec.html#resources) option. Here are some specs that include theirs:

```
JCAutocompletingSearch/0.9.2/JCAutocompletingSearch.podspec
JCAutocompletingSearch/0.9.3/JCAutocompletingSearch.podspec
JCAutocompletingSearch/0.9.4/JCAutocompletingSearch.podspec
JCAutocompletingSearch/0.9.5/JCAutocompletingSearch.podspec
JCAutocompletingSearch/0.9.6/JCAutocompletingSearch.podspec
Keystone-Contacts-iOS/1.1.4/Keystone-Contacts-iOS.podspec
LumberjackConsole/2.0.0/LumberjackConsole.podspec
LumberjackConsole/2.0.1/LumberjackConsole.podspec
Mixpanel/2.1.0/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.2.0/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.2.1/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.2.2/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.2.3/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.3.0/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.3.1/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.3.2/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.3.4/Mixpanel.podspec
Mixpanel/2.3.5/Mixpanel.podspec
OpenBLE/1.0.0/OpenBLE.podspec
```

Comment: Thanks. Looks like it is possible to include storyboard. I manage to include in my pod, but once I localised it (Base storyboard with strings), things don't work.

Comment: You'd have to also include the strings files if you want those in the pod as well.

Comment: I did. It's all in the bundle, and I verified the structure (refer to my post).

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem by using this line code to get bundle

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: type(of: self))
```

Answer (score 0):

I currently have the same issue here. While not answering the question itself, I'd like to provide additional information that most likely is valid in your case, too:

Calling

```
NSString *path = [bundle pathForResource:@"MyStoryboard" ofType:@"storyboard"];
NSLog(@"path: %@",path);
```

will print

```
/var/mobile/Containers/Bundle/Application/_identifier_/MyApp.app/MyBundle.bundle/Base.lproj/MyStoryboard.storyboard
```

i.e. the storyboard itself is found, but not loadable "the normal way".