# How to load resource in cocoapods resource_bundle

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have struggled a lot to how to load resource in cocoapods resource_bundle.

The following is what i put in the `.podspecs` file.

```
s.source_files = 'XDCoreLib/Pod/Classes/**/*'
s.resource_bundles = {
'XDCoreLib' => ['XDCoreLib/Pod/Resources/**/*.{png,storyboard}']
}
```

This is what I am trying to do from the main project.

```
let bundle = NSBundle(forClass: XDWebViewController.self)
let image = UIImage(named: "ic_arrow_back", inBundle: bundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
print(image)
```

I did see the picture in the `XDCoreLib.bundle`, but it return a nil.

Comment: Don't do that, just copy these resources into your project because these resources in pods can be updated / removed any time.

Comment: This pod is maintained by ourselves. The project size is growing bigger and bigger, and we want to separate each module.

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I struggled with a similar issue for a while. The resource bundle for a pod is actually a separate bundle from where your code lives. Try the following:

**Swift 5**

```
let frameworkBundle = Bundle(for: XDWebViewController.self)
let bundleURL = frameworkBundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent("XDCoreLib.bundle")
let resourceBundle = Bundle(url: bundleURL!)

let image = UIImage(named: "ic_arrow_back", in: resourceBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
print(image)
```

**-- ORIGINAL ANSWER --**

```
let frameworkBundle = NSBundle(forClass: XDWebViewController.self)
let bundleURL = frameworkBundle.resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("XDCoreLib.bundle")
let resourceBundle = NSBundle(URL: bundleURL!)
let image = UIImage(named: "ic_arrow_back", inBundle: resourceBundle, compatibleWithTraitCollection: nil)
print(image)
```

Comment: @Quaid What is XDWebViewController.self in first line

Comment: @Siddh The `XDWebViewController.self` should be a class inside the pod.

Comment: expanding on what @MattRobinson said, you can substitute `XDWebViewController.self` for any class that is inside the pod. the goal of that line of code is to identify the framework bundle by using any class belonging to the framework (pod)

Comment: @Quaid I'm able to load resources this way, but one question when I'm printing bundle object in debug window this "NSBundle <bundlePath> (not yet loaded)" is coming. what is this "not yet loaded" meaning here.

Answer (score 13):

I don't think any of the other answers have described the relationship to the Podspec. The bundle URL uses the name of the pod and then `.bundle` to find the resource bundle. This approach works with asset catalogs for accessing pod images both inside and outside of the pod.

**Podspec**

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
  s.name             = 'PodName'
  s.resource_bundles = {
    'ResourceBundleName' => ['path/to/resources/*/**']
  }
end
```

**Objective-C**

```
// grab bundle using `Class` in pod source (`self`, in this case)
NSBundle *bundle = [NSBundle bundleForClass:self.classForCoder];
NSURL *bundleURL = [[bundle resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"PodName.bundle"];
NSBundle *resourceBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];
UIImage *podImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"image_name" inBundle:resourceBundle compatibleWithTraitCollection:nil];
```

**Swift**

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35903720/856336).

Answer (score 6):

This will work

In `.podspec` add `s.resources` in addition to `s.resource_bundles` (`pod install` afterwards)

```
s.resources = 'XDCoreLib/Pod/Resources/**/*.{png,storyboard}'
```

Then in your code, its as easy as:

```
let image = UIImage(named: "image_name.png", in: Bundle(for: type(of: self)), compatibleWith: nil)
```

***Note***: You may need to run `pod install` after updating the `.podspec` to have the changes to your Xcode proj

Comment: it should be __s.resource = 'XDCoreLib/Pod/Resources/**/*.{png,storyboard}'__ rather then __s.resources = 'XDCoreLib/Pod/Resources/**/*.{png,storyboard}'__

Comment: Please note this will only work if your cocoapod is not a static framework. make sure  s.static_framework should be false in podspec. For static frameworks the only solution is to use separate bundles.

Answer (score 4):

You can just check the ID of the Bundle by selecting the Pods project, selecting the desired target, and making sure you're on the General tab.

[image]

Then in code you can load say an image in that Pod like so:

```
backgroundImageView.image = UIImage(named: "business_fellas", in: Bundle(identifier: "org.cocoapods.StandardLibrary3-0"), compatibleWith: nil)
```

Comment: This works for me when building a static library but it doesn't work for me when building a framework. That's because the framework and the resource bundle will both have the same bundle identifier and the bundle returned to by `Bundle()` will be the framework bundle (`.framework`) and the the resource bundle (`.bundle`) which contains the resources.

Answer (score 2):

Can create an extension to access the framework bundle easier in your framework source code

```
extension Bundle {
   static func getResourcesBundle() -> Bundle? {
      let bundle = Bundle(for {your class}.self)
      guard let resourcesBundleUrl = bundle.resourceURL?.appendingPathComponent({bundle name}) else {
         return nil
      }
      return Bundle(url: resourcesBundleUrl)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just for the record: I wanted to open a NIB from a Category stored in a CocoaPods library. Of course `[self classForCoder]` gave `UIKit` back (because of the Category), so the above methods didn't work.

I resolved the issue using some hardcoded paths:

```
NSURL *bundleURL = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] resourceURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Frameworks/MyCocoaPodLibraryName.framework"];
NSBundle *podBundle = [NSBundle bundleWithURL:bundleURL];

CustomView *customView = [[podBundle loadNibNamed:@"CustomView" owner:self options:nil] firstObject];
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like for some reason ****/*.{extensions}** pattern is required for this to work I ended up creating my podspec like this

```
s.resource_bundle = { '<BundleName>' => 'Pod/Resources/**/*.storyboard' }
s.resource = 'Pod/Resources/**/*.storyboard'
```

even though my actual path is *Pod/Resources/*.storyboard*

And then to find my bundle I used
[@Jhelzer's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46941077/3876832) although any way to get bundle e.g. by class or URL or bundleID will work after above setup.

You can also have a look into [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26527789/3876832) for more refrences.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting thing is when you need to do it in the source files that are also in the cocoapod library
I faced it when used a xib and plist files in my pod.

That was solved in the next way. Example of loading a xib file:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: self.classForCoder)
let viewController = CocoapodViewController(nibName: "CocoapodViewController", bundle: bundle)
```

Answer (score 0):

```swift
import class Foundation.Bundle

private class BundleFinder {}

extension Foundation.Bundle {
    /// Returns the resource bundle associated with the current Swift module.
    static var module: Bundle = {
        let bundleName = "ID3TagEditor_ID3TagEditorTests"

        let candidates = [
            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into an App.
            Bundle.main.resourceURL,

            // Bundle should be present here when the package is linked into a framework.
            Bundle(for: BundleFinder.self).resourceURL,

            // For command-line tools.
            Bundle.main.bundleURL,
        ]

        for candidate in candidates {
            let bundlePath = candidate?.appendingPathComponent(bundleName + ".bundle")
            if let bundle = bundlePath.flatMap(Bundle.init(url:)) {
                return bundle
            }
        }
        fatalError("unable to find bundle named ID3TagEditor_ID3TagEditorTests")
    }()
}
```

From: https://www.fabrizioduroni.it/2020/10/19/swift-package-manager-resources/

Answer (score 0):

For me the following worked because I'm using a static pod.

```
s.resource_bundle = '<BundleName>' => 'Path to resources'
s.resource = 'Path to resources'
```