# How to embedded Images and use those Images when creating custom cocoapod in iOS, swift 4

Tags: ios, uiimage, cocoapods, nsbundle, ios-frameworks

**WHAT I DID.**

I'm creating my own cocoapod Library. inside my library there are two directories **`Classes`** and **`Assets`**. I put all my **`.swift`** files into **`Classess`** directory and I can access those classes properly. Then I tried to add images by adding images into **`Assets`** directory. Then it creates a another **`Resources`** folder for me and inside that folder I can see all my **`.png`** files.

**WHAT I EXPECTED**

now I'm trying to access those images from my **`.swift`** files. as an example thinks that I have **`myviewcontroller.swif`** file which has **`UIImageView`** inside it. then I tried :

```
myimageView.Image = UIImage(named:"myimage.png")
```

This gives me a nil value.

**MORE DETAILS :**

here is my **`podspec`** file.

```
Pod::Spec.new do |s|
    s.name             = 'bottlenecLibrary'
    s.version          = '0.1.6'
    s.summary          = 'palm ios sdk for developers'
    s.swift_version    = '4.0'

# This description is used to generate tags and improve search results.
#   * Think: What does it do? Why did you write it? What is the focus?
#   * Try to keep it short, snappy and to the point.
#   * Write the description between the DESC delimiters below.
#   * Finally, don't worry about the indent, CocoaPods strips it!

s.description      = <<-DESC
This libraray includes all necessary resources for developers
DESC

s.homepage         = 'https://bitbucket.org/palm/palmiossdk'
# s.screenshots     = 'www.example.com/screenshots_1', 'www.example.com/screenshots_2'
s.license          = { :type => 'MIT', :file => 'LICENSE' }
s.author           = { 'palm group' => 'pods@palm.com' }
s.source           = { :git => 'https://palmss@bitbucket.org/palm/palmiossdk.git', :tag => s.version.to_s }
# s.social_media_url = 'https://twitter.com/<TWITTER_USERNAME>'

s.ios.deployment_target = '9.0'

s.source_files = 'bottlenecLibrary/Classes/**/*'

s.resource_bundles = {
    'bottlenecLibrary' => ['bottlenecLibrary/Assets/*.png', 'bottlenecLibrary/Assets/*.xcassets', 'bottlenecLibrary/Resources/*.png']
}
# s.public_header_files = 'Pod/Classes/**/*.h'
# s.frameworks = 'UIKit', 'MapKit'
 s.dependency 'Alamofire', '~> 4.7'

end
```

I tried with adding all these : `['bottlenecLibrary/Assets/*.png', 'bottlenecLibrary/Assets/*.xcassets', 'bottlenecLibrary/Resources/*.png']` but nothing worked.

Note : I tried to read the image using  bundle also.

Hope your help with this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To get images in a CocoaPod you definitely need to call it specifying the bundle:

```
let bundle = Bundle(for: [A_CLASS_IN_YOUR_COCOAPOD].self)
let bundleURL = bundle.resourceURL?.URLByAppendingPathComponent("[YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME].bundle")
let resourceBundle = NSBundle(URL: bundleURL!)
UIImage(named: [IMAGE_NAME_STRING], in: resourceBundle, compatibleWith: nil)
```

`[YOUR_BUNDLE_NAME]` would be `bottlenecLibrary` in this case.

Source: [How to load resource in cocoapods resource_bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692265/how-to-load-resource-in-cocoapods-resource-bundle)

Comment: this doesn't work for me. I tried from a file in my pod. it gives me a nil value for image

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: Thanks for your answer and time on this. it works perfectly.