# How to define Bundle as internal For Pod Lib and SPM that handles both of them For using package images

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, swift-package-manager

I write a package that contains **"media.xcassests"** file, the media file contains some images.
I could access my images with below code with **SPM(Swift Package Manager)** (add package from github):

```
UImage(named: "MyImage", in: Bundle.module, compatibleWith: nil)
```

When I add the repo to "Pod Lib" (https://cocoapods.org/) with .podspec file

**"Bundle.module"** syntax causes an error(type bundle has no member module) for pod validating with the below command:

```
> pod lib lint
```

[image]

I change it to below code and the issue solved:

```
UImage(named: "MyImage", in: Bundle(for: MyClass.self), compatibleWith: nil)
```

but the SPM can't load the image

I think the Bundle definition causes the issue

the package.swift file has

```
resources: [.process("Resources")]
```

I trid to change some Bundle definition like as all of defintion in this link:

[How to load resource in cocoapods resource_bundle](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35692265/how-to-load-resource-in-cocoapods-resource-bundle)

I also use from below code but the issue didn't solve:

```
let podBundle = Bundle(for: ImageHelper.self)
if let url = podBundle.url(forResource: "ForceUpdateKit", withExtension: "bundle") {
    let bundle = Bundle(url: url)
    return UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
}
```

but the issue still there.

Finally when I use from "Bundle.module" **SPM** works and **POD** not work and When I use "Bundle(for: MyClass.self)" **POD** works and **SPM** not works.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 solutions:

Solution 1:

```
class ImageHelper {
    static var resolvedBundle: Bundle {
#if SWIFT_PACKAGE
        return Bundle.module
#else
        return Bundle(for: self)
#endif
    }
    
    static func image(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
        return UIImage(named: name,
                       in: resolvedBundle,
                       compatibleWith: nil)
    }
}
```

Solution 2:

```
class ImageHelper {
    static func image(_ name: String) -> UIImage? {
        let podBundle = Bundle(for: ImageHelper.self)
        if let url = podBundle.url(forResource: "YourPackageName_YourPackageName", withExtension: "bundle") {
            let bundle = Bundle(url: url)
            return UIImage(named: name, in: bundle, compatibleWith: nil)
        } else {
            return UIImage(named: name,
                           in: Bundle(for: ImageHelper.self),
                           compatibleWith: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

you can find your resource name or bundle name: when you go to definition of Bundle.module (you should build once your project) you can see the bundle name like as: "YourPackageName_YourPackageName" it goes to "**resource_bundle_accessor**" file

[image]