# Creating storyboard in pod

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoapods

I am creating my own pod and I'm trying to create a storyboard inside the pod with no luck.

Is it possible to create a storyboard inside the pod ? and how can I do that ?

Comment: YES. You need to also add in the podpsec resources the storyboard: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292306/creating-a-custom-cocoa-pod-with-a-storyboard-in-it But it's unclear where lies exactly your issue.

Comment: How can I use it in my project ? I'm unable to do this , I have a ViewController in my pod that i want to show on top of the current VC in my project

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Creating a custom cocoa pod with a storyboard in it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23292306/creating-a-custom-cocoa-pod-with-a-storyboard-in-it)